# Interfaces podem ser instanciadas?

Tags: java, android, interface

Olá. Eu sei que interfaces não podem ser instanciadas, mas eu me deparei com um código que não faz muito sentido, para mim.

```
EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
String name = nameField.getText().toString();
```

Essa segunda linha que me deixou confuso. `nameField` é uma instância de `EditText`. O método `getText()` é chamado pelo objeto. Esse método retorna um objeto do tipo `Editable`, que chama o método `toString()`? Minha interpretação está correta?

Por que a classe `Editable` é uma interface. Como pode ser instanciada, neste exemplo? Alguém pode me esclarecer o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 4):

O único detalhe errado nesse seu código de exemplo é que a variável da primeira linha tem o mesmo nome da variável da segunda linha, o que não compila. Essas variáveis precisariam ter nomes diferentes. Ou seja, ele teria que ser assim:

```
EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
String name = nameField.getText().toString();
```

Você não pode instanciar interfaces diretamente, mas pode intanciar classes que a implementem. Por exemplo:

```
public interface Animal {
    public String fazerBarulho();
}

public class Cachorro implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String fazerBarulho() {
        return "au au";
    }
}

public class Gato implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String fazerBarulho() {
        return "miau";
    }
}

public class Teste1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // O tipo das variáveis é de uma interface,
        // mas o que é instanciado são as classes que a implementam.
        Animal x = new Cachorro();
        Animal y = new Gato();

        System.out.println(x.fazerBarulho()); // Imprime "au au".
        System.out.println(y.fazerBarulho()); // Imprime "miau".
    }
}
```

Observe que o tipo das variáveis são de interfaces, mas o que é instanciado de verdade são classes que as implementam.

De volta ao seu código, temos então que o tipo da variável da primeira linha é um `EditText` (uma classe). Ao chamar o `getText()`, um objeto do tipo `Editable` é fornecido. O `Editable` é uma interface, mas o objeto obtido é o de alguma classe que implementa essa interface. Nesse objeto do tipo `Editable`, o método `toString()` é invocado, fornecendo então uma `String`.

Todo objeto tem um método chamdo `toString()` porque esse método é definido na classe `Object` e como todas as demais classes são subclasses de `Object`, logo, elas irão herdar esse método e frequentemente sobreescrevê-lo. Por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Meu nome é " + nome + " e tenho " + idade + " anos";
    }
}

public class Pedra {
}

public class Teste2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa carlos = new Pessoa("Carlos", 25);
        Pedra p = new Pedra();

        // Imprime "Meu nome é Carlos e tenho 25 anos".
        System.out.println(carlos.toString());

        // Imprime algo silimar a "Pedra@5c0d3c".
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Nesse caso acima, a classe `Pessoa` sobreescreve o método `toString()`, de forma que quando ele for invocado, uma `String` útil é produzida. Já a classe `Pedra`, não sobreescreve esse método, ficando com o que foi herdado da classe `Object` que não é um método particularmente muito útil.